# how to sum the number of objects in different images in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sum, connected-components

this is my entire code. What i did here is to try to find matching points between an image and a template i substracted from the image.

The first loop and second loop extract all the card from the original image(first image with set of card)
The next part of the code is just finding the matching point between extracted card and the template.
The last for loop i created, is based on range of the matching points count I selected to discard cards that have less matching with the template.(selectCard)
Then I created the for loop to (selectCard) and I applied connected components to count the objects remaining on the card when They pass the selection criteria.

So I need to get the total number of object of all the card that pass the selection criteria I have made. Basically, I got a result of each card. Not all the card. I need to compute the result of All those cards.

```
  for j=1:max(max(LabeledImage))

  [row, col] = find(LabeledImage==j);

  len=max(row)-min(row)+2;
  breadth=max(col)-min(col)+2;
  Img=uint8(zeros([len breadth 3] ));
   sy=min(col)-1;
  sx=min(row)-1;

  for i=1:size(row,1)
   x=row(i,1)-sx;
  y=col(i,1)-sy;
  Img(x,y,:)=grayImage(row(i,1),col(i,1),:);
  end
  mytitle=strcat('Card Number:',num2str(j));
  % figure,imshow(Img);title(mytitle);
  Img=rgb2gray(Img);
  pointsForSpade1 = detectHarrisFeatures(Img);
  pointsForSpade2 = detectHarrisFeatures(Template_for_spade);

  %extract neighborhood features
  [featuresForSpade1,valid_pointsForSpade1] = 
  extractFeatures(Img,pointsForSpade1);
  [featuresForSpade2,valid_pointsForSpade2] = 
  extractFeatures(Template_for_spade,pointsForSpade2);
  %Match the features
  indexPairs = matchFeatures(featuresForSpade1,featuresForSpade2);
  %retrieve the locations of the corresponding points for each image.
  matchedPointsForSpade1 = valid_pointsForSpade1(indexPairs(:,1),:);
  matchedPointsForSpade2 = valid_pointsForSpade2(indexPairs(:,2),:);
    % visualize the corresponding points.

   figure,subplot(5,5,j)


  showMatchedFeatures(Img,Template_for_spade,matchedPointsForSpade1,.....
     matchedPointsForSpade2, 'montage');

 count1 = matchedPointsForSpade1.Count;
 %disp(matchedPoints1);
 selectCard4 = find(count1>10);
 Total = 0;
 for e4= 1: selectCard4
 figure, subplot(5,5,j) 
showMatchedFeatures(Img(e4),Template_for_spade,matchedPointsForSpade1,...
 matchedPointsForSpade2, 'montage');
     title(Name);


  % eliminate not needed hole on the card. 
  level = 0.57;
  Img2 = imbinarize(Img, level);

 %Morphological operation
 ImgComp = imcomplement(Img2);
 se = strel('disk', 10);
 Iopened = imopen(ImgComp, se);
%figure;
 %imshow(Iopened);
[Label3, numObject4] = bwlabel(Iopened);
TotalSpade = sum(numObject4);

 s = sprintf('\n card number: of this set has #%s spades',j, 
 num2str(TotalSpade));
  disp(s);
 end

  end
```

I want to display the sum of connected objects based on selected card.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. `bwlabel` will return the number of components found, so it's just a matter of summing the two numbers.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited in case you want to still help!!

Comment: @steve Your code is just finding the connected components of the same image `Iopened` over and over again and `sum` is not doing anything, but it looks like it should print the correct number of components for that one image. What exactly do you want your code to do differently? Also, if you're responding somebody you should ping them like @beaker so they get notified. Otherwise they don't know you've responded to them (in general... there are exceptions).

Comment: Mr. @beaker check this out please. I edited my code.

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting the correct images shown in your loop? The loop index `e4 = 1:selectCard4` looks like it should be `e4 = selectCard4`. You should also indent your code properly, it will be much easier to read. In the MATLAB editor type `ctrl-A` to select all and then `ctrl-I` to autoindent your code.

Comment: @baker, I have changed the the loop Index, to "e4 = selectCard4" I still dont have accurate result. The loop is still giving me the objects on each card. Not the total amount of objects for all the card.    Do you still have any suggestion Sir? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main problems here. First, you initialize `Total = 0;` and then change the variable name to `TotalSpade`. Change the initialization to:

```
TotalSpade = 0;
```

Second, the assignment to `TotalSpade` is overwriting the previous value. In order to accumulate the total, you need to *add* to `TotalSpade` instead. Also, `numObject4` is a scalar, so `sum` doesn't do anything.

```
TotalSpade = TotalSpade + numObject4;
```

Finally, if you only want to print the total of the objects, you need to take your print statement outside the loop. You can also use `fprintf` instead of `sprintf`+`disp` since `fprintf` prints to the console if you don't specify a file descriptor.

```
for e4 = 1:selectCard4
   ...
end
fprintf('\n card number: of this set has #%s spades', j,
     num2str(TotalSpade));
```

Comment: Thank you Baker Work. Perfectly.

Comment: Thank you @beaker Perfectly. I put the for Total_diamonds After All the for loop it gave me the result I want. Thank you for your time. So to print each object from each card I did my previous methods and to print the total of all objects from all the cards at the same time I used yours. Hope it can helps someone one days.